React Native Expo Standalone white screen
In my react native expo standalone app I have a SignIn and Home component. When I signin and navigate to the home page my app gets stuck in a white screen but if I close the app and reopen it the app opens the home screen. Everything works fine in the development. The problem only in the standalone after eas build -p android.
Home component:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Header from '../Header-Footer/Header';
import Footer from '../Header-Footer/Footer';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { useData } from '../DataContext';
import { Table, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';
import { Session } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import { getUserRoles } from '../../supabase';

interface NavigationProps {
  session: Session | null; 
}
const Home:React.FC<NavigationProps> = ({session}) => {
  const { data } = useData(); 
  const { setData } = useData();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (session) {
      getRoles();
    }
  }, [session]);
  const getRoles = async ()=>{
    const roles = await getUserRoles();
    const hasRole = roles!.includes('daily-image-maker') || roles!.includes('system-admin');
    const dataValue = hasRole ? 'true' : null;
    setData(dataValue);
  }
  const tableHead = ["Tasks of Today"];
  const tableData = [
    ["You don't have messages today"],
  ];
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['#004fec', '#000a20']}
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }} 
        end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
        style={styles.gradient}
      >
      <Header />
      <View style={[styles.mainContent]}>
         <Table style={{marginTop:40, width:"90%", borderColor: 'grey' ,}} >
            <Row
               data={tableHead}
               style={{ height: 40,borderRadius:30 , borderWidth:5 , borderBottomWidth:0,
                        borderBottomRightRadius:0, borderBottomLeftRadius:0,borderColor: 'grey',                        
                      }}
               textStyle= {styles.HeaderText}
               
            />
            <Rows 
                data={tableData} 
                style={{ height: 80, borderRadius:30 , borderWidth:5 ,
                         borderTopRightRadius:0, borderTopLeftRadius:0,borderColor: 'grey' }} 
                textStyle={styles.HeaderText}
            />
         </Table>
      </View>
        <Footer data={data}/>
      </LinearGradient>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gradient: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor:'#000080',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  headerText:{
    fontSize:22,
    justifyContent:'flex-start',
    marginLeft:60,
    marginTop:10,
    color:'#0018f9',
  },
  mainContent: {
    height:'66%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor:'white',    
    borderTopLeftRadius:50,
    borderBottomRightRadius:50,
  },
  HeaderText:{ textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold" }
});

export default Home;

I tried to logcat and debug the problem but couldn't find any errors. This is how I build my app:
eas build -p android --profile preview
"preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "channel": "preview"
    },


Can you add code of your Home component? Issue might be because of some value which the screen is trying to fetch might be undefined for the first render after the signIn but subsequent renders might find the value so working fine with subsequent renders.

@SourabhSudheer I Updated my question with the home component.

Well, the issue you are facing is because you have imported "Session" from supabase but you are using "session". @mustafa ibrahim
